# ASP.NET MVC 4 Applying Windows Authentication to a single Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 application which is open to all users, no login needed. There is **one controller only** which I need to apply **Windows Authentication** to via a Web.Config, like this:

```
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="domain\jsmith" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

The controller would **MySite.Com/MyApp/MyAdminReportController**

If this is possible, how?

Comment: Sounds like `Area` to me: http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/asp-net-mvc-areasa-better-way-to-structure-the-application/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just need Windows auth and specify paths which are only need authorization. If you don't need Forms auth as well it looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ......
    <authentication mode="Windows">
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <location path="MyAdminReport">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

This is web config approach, other options is adding [Authorize] attribute to your controllers (even not hole controller you can add this attr for only specific actions too).

```
[Authorize]
public class MyAdminReportController : Controller
{

   //[Authorize]
   public ActionResult PrivatePage()
   {
      return View();
   }


}
```

Comment: A path is required for `location path` not the controller name. So it should read `path="MyAdminReport"`. If multiple routes/paths lead to the controller all of them need to be listed.

Comment: Yeah you're right "Controller" suffix should be removed, thanks for the heads up.